# Excel column compare and match

Tags: excel

I have a report which shows the ID#s and the names corresponding to those IDs.

I am trying to write a formula which check the ID# and see if the same ID#s have the same Name;

If the same ID #s  are listed more then once and they have different names then it should show that the IDs and names do not match.

The idea is that same ID#s should have the same name; if the same IDs have different names then it should show that ID have different names.

```
Col A     Col B       Col C

ID        Name         Desired Output
3         Peter        ID with multiple names
3         Ken          ID with multiple names
5         Chris        match
5         Chris        match
5         Chris        match
6         Dave         match
6         Dave         match
7         Lisa         match
8         Mark         match
10        Ken          match 
12        Frank        ID with Multiple names
12        Randy        ID with Multiple names  
12        Frank        ID with Multiple names 
12        Mike         ID with Multiple names
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>" &B2),"ID with multiple names","match")
```

[image]